# Access Database - Most Recent Record - Max Function

Tags: sql, ms-access, max

I'm in the process of building a database to keep track of loaning equipment. I'm trying to build a query that will display the latest record of each machines location.

Relevant table is:

Movements:

- Movement ID (PK)
- EntryDate (Automatically generated on record entry)
- Serial (FK from a table called stock, with (Make, Model etc)
- Location (Where the machine is)
- Status (Things like: Available, Testing, Sold etc)

Current query is:

```
SELECT Movements.Serial, Max(Movements.EntryDateMovements) AS MaxOfEntryDateMovements
FROM Movements
GROUP BY Movements.Serial;
```

Which spits out the latest date of a record, and the serial associated with it.

What I need is the status to be shown in the results, but it still be grouped by the serial.

My issue is that when I try and add that, it either comes back with an error with about the expression not being part of the aggregate function, or I get more results than expected, as it no longer just keeps the results unique to the serial.

I'm pretty new Access, and have so far been able to muddle through guides, and books, and this site, to get everything else working, but i'm stuck at this hurdle.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select top 1 *
from Movements
order by EntryDateMovements desc
```

This will give you everything for the newest record. This is TSQL but I think it carries over to Access.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select  t.serial,t.EntryDateMovements ,t.location, t.status 
From movements as t
Inner join (SELECT Movements.Serial, Max(Movements.EntryDateMovements) AS MaxOfEntryDateMovements
FROM Movements
GROUP BY Movements.Serial) as MaxMovements on t.serial= MaxMovements.serial and t.EntryDateMovements=MaxMovements.MaxOfEntryDateMovements
```